# How to name key RPG concepts in Java?

Tags: java, rpg

I'm writing a basic RPG at the moment, with characters, races, classes, and the characters evolve on maps, naturally.

How to go around the default names that exist in `java.lang` and `java.util`. I'm having a hard time trying to find equivalent names to the following RPG concepts that do not clash with Java basic utilities. Typically, the words `Character`, `Class` and `Map` cause me trouble. For instance this is how typically clashes would occur:

```
// Line 322, well below the imports
char[] characters = new String("foo").toCharArray();
Character character = new Character();
Map map = getMap();
Class heroClass = getDefaultClass();
// do stuff
```

In this example, it's hard to tell if `Character` is `java.lang.Character` or `mygame.engine.Character`. What type is `Map`? Can anyone answer without seeing the imports?

I could use the fully qualified name:

```
java.lang.Character c = new String("foo").toCharArray()[0];
mygame.engine.Character character = new mygame.engine.Character();
java.util.Map map = getMap();
mygame.engine.Class heroClass = getDefaultClass();
// Do stuff.
```

But in the long run, and from experience, this is barely readable.

So I'd like to know what are usual techniques and/or synonyms that people use to both avoid confusion and unreadable code.

I have personally thought of using the prefix `Game`, which will lead to using `Game` a lot of times: `GameClass`, `GameCharacter`, `GameMap`. I think this is meh, but I can get over with it if people say it's not so unusual.

I'm not asking opinions: I'm looking for alternatives, such as which synonyms are used and are clear enough, or other techniques that don't decrease the readability of the code.

Comment: In java you can name the classes whatever you want except for the reserved keywords. There should not be any conflucts, if you import the correct packages. `public class Class` is no problem

Comment: Yes, but if you read the code, as a Java programmer, you kind of expect `Class` to be `java.lang.Class`. I didn't write that down because it seemed kind of obvious. I'll edit to reflect that.

Comment: Put your classes your own packages. This is what these are for....

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire and thats a problem why?

Comment: As said just above, it doesn't remove the confusion...

Comment: What is confusing with `mygame.CharacterClass`, `mygame.Character` and `mygame.Map`?

Comment: I would probably prefix Game onto the start of my classes. GameMap, GameCharacter. or if you have a name or codename for your game prefix that. If your game was called Skyrim; SkyrimMap and SkyrimCharacter could make nice class names. Also for the record its only for your own use, you could name the abc or xyz for what its worth. I personally would avoid using custom class names that look close to language stuff, for example at work we have custom namespace (package) names that are the same as .NET namespaces, it can get very confusing and leads to you qualifying the full name.

Comment: @lozzajp You might want to add this as an answer.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt it's long, my packages aren't just a 3-letter package. Fully qualified name are even more confusing. You should try once to remove all of your imports in your code and use fully qualified name, you'll see how unreadable it is. lozzajp's answer actually make more sense: if I want to qualify, I should put it directly in the simple class name (as opposed to fully qualified class name).

Comment: Voting to close as opinion based.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt The question is "what are alternative names". How is it opinion-based? You forced me into your opinion about packages... I tried to stay out of it.

Comment: Character -> Actor, Class -> Profession or Specialization. I'm not really sure what you're describing as a map. Like a paper map with locations? Perhaps you could use 'Zone'. If it's like an actual map, then I would probably say 'GameMap' is sufficient, as it would be a 'subclass'.

Comment: I rewrote the entire question, hopefully making my intent clear. I'm not asking for opinions (though you may give yours if you want).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would probably prefix Game onto the start of my classes. GameMap, GameCharacter. or if you have a name or codename for your game prefix that. If your game was called Skyrim; SkyrimMap and SkyrimCharacter could make nice class names.

Also if its only for your own use, you could name the abc or xyz for what its worth.

I personally would avoid using custom class names that look close to language stuff, for example at work we have custom namespace (package) names that are the same as .NET namespaces, it can get very confusing and leads to you qualifying the full name

Hope that helps.

P.S. alternatively as others suggested just use the names but in your own package, so it all looks like Game.Character, Game.Class etc.

Comment: The convention `GamenameClass` gets awkward when you program a (spiritual) successor with a different name and want to reuse code. If Bethesda would have followed that convention, the class for characters in Skyrim would likely be called `OblivionClass` or even `MorrowindClass`. It can also lead to [Smurf Naming Convention](https://blog.codinghorror.com/new-programming-jargon/).

Comment: Well, `TESClass` would be more appropriate then, but the point is nice. All I previously thought was `GameClass` where `<real-game-name>Class` is better.

Comment: @Philipp I have heard of people using codenames in development source code for reasons as this. The game name may change just days before launch plans start happening and announcements. So just a codename is given and stuck to by everyone to avoid confusions etc. Very good point about the successors though.

Comment: A shorter addition than 'Game' I sometimes use is 'My' e.g. 'MyTextDraw'. I work alone and so it is at least clear to me. I also use words like 'Enemy' rather than 'character'. You could use other synonyms such as 'Plan' for 'Map'. I would avoid using the name of the game because it makes it much harder to re-use and compare different games.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly advice to use java analog of [namespaces](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace).

They are called **packages**.

You can read about packages there:

http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch02_11.htm

Comment: Thanks, but you didn't read the whole question. Please read the last two paragraphs of my question to see why your answer is not useful at all. Also, on a side note, I have 18 years of experience in Java: it's only the first time I'm coding a RPG. I only have difficulties with naming in this very precise context. I don't have any trouble with Java concepts.

Comment: Yeah, I got your point.